# how to get the mean of every factor in each date in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

i got this code

```
plot3 <- 
  ggplot(data = df_clean, mapping = aes(x = LastPerformanceReview_Date, y= EngagementSurvey, group = Department, color = Department)) +
  geom_line()

ggplotly(plot3)
```

and then the result is :[image]

then I check the data  [image]

there are data on people from the same department and reviewed on the same date

my question is how to get the mean value of the department for each day and how to change the x axis which only shows the year so that it can show the day and month

Answer (score 1):

please consider sharing some of your data using dput().

You can control the breaks and labels for your x-axis using scale_x_date(). To include day and month in the labels you'd include:

```
scale_x_date(date_labels = "%d %b %Y")
```

Given the period covered, I would caution against adding too many breaks.

Here is a dplyr method for summarizing the means for each department by date:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Department, LastPerformanceReview_Date) %>%
  summarize(dailyAvg = mean(EngagementSurvey))
```